# ERROR: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException : Error creating object with name 'NHibernate SessionFactory' defined in 'assembly'

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, spring.net

I get the following error when running any NUnit integration test

```
- Assembly setup complete -
Beginning Processing of Tests -
Test 'PXL.IntegrationTests.EventDaoTests.deleteEvent' failed: Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException : Error creating object with name 'NHibernateSessionFactory' defined in 'assembly [PXL.Dao.NHibernate, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null], resource [PXL.Dao.NHibernate.Dao.Dao.xml] line 18' : Initialization of object failed : Association references unmapped class: PXL.Domain.TBEvent
  ----> NHibernate.MappingException : Association references unmapped class: PXL.Domain.TBEvent
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectFactoryUtils.ObjectsOfTypeIncludingAncestors(IListableObjectFactory factory, Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
at Spring.Dao.Support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.DetectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(IListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
at Spring.Dao.Attributes.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.set_ObjectFactory(IObjectFactory value)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.CreateAndCacheSingletonInstance(String objectName, RootObjectDefinition objectDefinition, Object[] arguments)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractObjectFactory.GetObjectInternal(String name, Type requiredType, Object[] arguments, Boolean suppressConfigure)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.DefaultListableObjectFactory.GetObjectsOfType(Type type, Boolean includePrototypes, Boolean includeFactoryObjects)
at Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.RegisterObjectPostProcessors(IConfigurableListableObjectFactory objectFactory)
at Spring.Context.Support.AbstractApplicationContext.Refresh()
at Spring.Testing.NUnit.AbstractSpringContextTests.LoadContextLocations(String[] locations)
at Spring.Testing.NUnit.AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests.SetUp()
--MappingException
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.BindCollectionSecondPass(XmlNode node, Collection model, IDictionary`2 persistentClasses, IDictionary`2 inheritedMetas)
at NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.CollectionBinder.<>c__DisplayClassd.<AddCollectionSecondPass>b__c(IDictionary`2 persistentClasses)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.SecondPassCompile()
at Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject.AfterPropertiesSet()
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InvokeInitMethods(Object target, String name, IConfigurableObjectDefinition definition)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.ConfigureObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, IObjectWrapper wrapper)
at Spring.Objects.Factory.Support.AbstractAutowireCapableObjectFactory.InstantiateObject(String name, RootObjectDefinition definition, Object[] arguments, Boolean allowEagerCaching, Boolean suppressConfigure)

Assembly TearDown

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 4.67 seconds (NUnit 2.5.5).
```

The line of code that the error refers to is the NHibernate Dao Configuration 1st line.

```
<!-- NHibernate Configuration -->
<object id="NHibernateSessionFactory" type="Spring.Data.NHibernate.LocalSessionFactoryObject, Spring.Data.NHibernate21" scope="application">
    <property name="DbProvider" ref="DbProvider"/>
    <property name="MappingAssemblies">
        <list>
            <value>PXL.Dao.NHibernate</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="HibernateProperties">
        <dictionary>
            <entry key="hibernate.connection.provider" value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider"/>
            <entry key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect"/>
            <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver"/>
        </dictionary>
    </property>

    <!-- provides integation with Spring's declarative transaction management features -->
    <property name="ExposeTransactionAwareSessionFactory" value="true" />
</object>
```

The missing file that it refers to "Association references unmapped class: PXL.Domain.TBEvent" does exist and as far as I can see there is nothing missing, the mapping file has no errors in it and there is a cs file for it to map to and all the interfaces exist and the row in the dao which refers to it also exists.

```
<object id="TBEventDao" type="PXL.Dao.NHibernate.HibernateTBEventDao, PXL.Dao.NHibernate">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="NHibernateSessionFactory"/>
</object>
```

I know this is something simple, wonder if anyone here can give me some insight.

Comment: Note: the code does compile with no warnings, this seems to occur when running integration tests and viewing any web page in the site, which to me would mean there is a problem with a mapping file, but usually a mapping file would have a different error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the *Build Action* of your mapping xml file is set to *Embedded Resource* and that the extension is `.hmb.xml`.

Comment: Thank you, Yes this was it :-) I Solved this problem yesterday, unfortunately stack overflow doesn't seem to allow me to answer my own question as I don't have a high enough ranking.

Comment: Ok, good to have this solved. I think you can answer your own question regardless of rep, but you have to wait one or two days after you post the question before you can answer.